# how to execute a statement when Where or orWhere clause is true in mulplie orWhere clauses

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to search relevant jobs from a list on jobs on my DB according to what user searches for and if the search term matches the job title its highly relevant search result so I am trying to assign the relevancy value to job objects right after their where condition gets satisfied. Also cleaner way of writing orWhere conditions?

```
    public function search()
    {
        $searchText = $_GET['searchText'];
        $jobs = Jobs::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%') //how to do $jobs->relevancy = 100 here? if this where condition is satisfied?
            ->orwhere('skills', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%')
            ->orwhere('desc', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%') //$jobs->relevancy = 10 here 
            ->orwhere('desc1', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%')
            ->orwhere('desc2', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%')
            ->orwhere('desc3', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%')
            ->orwhere('desc4', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchText . '%')
            ->get();

        return view('results', compact('jobs'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to know which part of the where clauses actually matched the query. You'd need to re-do the text comparisons after you got the results, which is probably not ideal.

In these sort of situations you might want to consider a full text search.

If you're using MySQL you can create a FULLTEXT index and then use [`MATCH ... AGAINST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). (other DBMS have a different syntax but generally there is support).

```
$searchText = request()->searchText;
  $jobs = Jobs::whereRaw('MATCH(name) AGAINST (? IN NATUAL LANGUAGE MODE)', [$searchText])
            ->orWhereRaw('MATCH(desc) AGAINST (? IN NATUAL LANGUAGE MODE)', [$searchText])
            // ...
            selectRaw('(100*MATCH(name) AGAINST (? IN NATUAL LANGUAGE MODE) + 10*MATCH(name) AGAINST (? IN NATUAL LANGUAGE MODE)) as score', [$searchText,searchText])
            ->addSelect("*")
            ->orderBy('score', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

MATCH ... AGAINST will return a relevance score so by doing e.g. `100*MATCH(name)..` you are adding a weight of 100 to that match. The overall result *should* be ordered based on the total relevance of the search.

More on full text search in MySQL [in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Yes assigning weights was exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group orWhere conditions to then apply another WHERE (AND) statement, you can use a closure for the grouping.

Imagine that you want something like this:

```
WHERE A 
AND (WHERE B OR WHERE C)
AND (WHERE D OR WHERE E)
```

Then you could do:

```
$results = Model::where('A', 'something')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('B', 'something')
            ->orWhere('C', 'something');
    })
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('D', 'something')
            ->orWhere('E', 'something');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: I see thank you.. But that also doesn't answer my main question. Please check my code i have added a comment for further clarification on what i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this kind of condition in many places then you can do the following!

1- In your AppServiceProvider inside boot methode

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
public function boot()
{
    Builder::macro('search', function($field, $string){
        return $string ? $this->where($field, 'like', '%'.$string.'%') : $this;
    });

    Builder::macro('orSearch', function($field, $string){
        return $string ? $this->orWhere($field, 'like', '%'.$string.'%') : $this;
    });
}
```

2- Do your Query like the following

```
$jobs = Jobs::where(function($query) {
   if($searchText != "") {
      $query->search('skills', $searchText);
      $query->orSearch('desc', $searchText);
      $query->orSearch('desc1', $searchText);
      $query->orSearch('desc2',$searchText);
      $query->orSearch('desc3',$searchText);
   }
   
})->get();
```

I think this is a cleaner way of doing this kind of query.